# Parsing error when bootstrapping on Windows

Tags: windows, juju

I am trying to get Juju working on Windows 8 but I am running in to some errors when trying to get juju to see my ssh keys:

```
C:\Users\username> juju bootstrap
error: error parsing environment "azure":
    read C:\Users\user\SkyDrive\Documents\Azure\ssh\: The handle is invalid.
```

I've added a public key I generated with putty to the directory above called azure

My `environments.yaml` file has this in it:

```
authorized-keys-path: C:\Users\user\SkyDrive\Documents\Azure\ssh\
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get this error if you quote the path? I think the : in C:\ is throwing this off. Try `authorized-keys-path: "C:\Users\user\SkyDrive\Documents\Azure\ssh"`

Comment: I'm having trouble finding documentation that points to `authorized-keys-path` -- is it supposed to be a directory or a file? (And what's it do? :)

Comment: Yes that seemed to work there thanks! But now I get another error with: error: cannot parse; C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Juju|enviornments.yaml\YAML error : line 126: did not find expected hexadecimal number - it seems that it does not like my subscritpion id that I created with a new azure account

Comment: @ClaudeTylerMcAdams Ask Ubuntu works best when you ask a question. If you have a different issue consider opening a new question with that. However, it's likely also a quoting issue. Please try quoting the value for your subscription id like you did for authorized-keys-path

Comment: @sarnold it's a global option that probably not documented anywhere. There's `authorized-keys-path` and `authorized-keys`. I'd be happy to answer that in another question :)

Comment: @ClaudeTylerMcAdams I go the same error but on a different line on the configuration file. I solved it by adding double slashes on the file-system path. For example instead of `"C:\Users\user\SkyDrive\Documents\Azure\ssh"` I used `"C:\\Users\\user\\SkyDrive\\Documents\\Azure\\ssh"`

Answer (score 7):

YAML can be quite picky about formatting, whenever you have something other than alpha numberics make sure to apply quotes.

```
authorized-keys-path: "C:\Users\user\SkyDrive\Documents\Azure\ssh\"
```

Should resolve the issue.