# "did not find expected hexadecimal number" when bootstraping Juju on Windows

Tags: windows-8, juju

With Juju on windows 8 I get the following error:

```
Cannot parse: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Juju|enviornments.yaml\YAML error : line 126: did not find expected hexadecimal number
```

It seems that it does not like my subscription id that I created with a new azure account.

Any ideas on how to fix this? It is a legitimate subscription id...

Comment: Can you ensure that the yaml formatting is correct? See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/368232/parsing-error-when-bootstrapping-on-windows

Comment: This seems the previous question to http://askubuntu.com/q/368232/169736 apparently op asked another question with more information but not the same error. I'd say that is safe to asume OP solved this problem and then was bothered with the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing error when bootstrapping on Windows](http://askubuntu.com/q/368232/10698)